# NameError: name 'f' is not defined when using pool.map(f, range()) in class

Tags: python, dictionary, pool

I'm new to python and I'm trying to load the CPU using pool.map(). The following code does the loading on the CPU when it is not included in a class

```
def f(x):
    while True:
        x*x

def load(cores):
    print('utilizing %d cores' % (cores/2))
    pool = Pool(10)
    pool.map(f, range(6))
```

However, when I put it in a class and try to run the code

```
class test_cpu:

    def f(x):
        while True:
            x*x

    def load(cores):
        print('utilizing %d cores' % (cores/2))
        pool = Pool(10)
        pool.map(f, range(6))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('There are %d CPUs in your PC' % multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    cores_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    input_user = input('What do you want to tes? type CPU, Memory or Both: ')
    input_user.lower()
    if input_user == 'cpu':
        test_cpu.load(cores_count)
```

when I type CPU it prints this error, stating that the function f is not defined

```
utilizing 4 cores
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_all.txt", line 81, in <module>
    test_cpu.load(cores_count)
  File "test_all.txt", line 45, in load
    pool.map(f, range(6))
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please update your question with your code which doesn’t work.

Comment: You should show the code that's not working. The problem is clearly related to `when I put it in a class`, but you don't show that so we can only guess what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If `f` becomes a method, you'd need to refer to it as `self.f`.

Comment: [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) ... [4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: @MarkMeyer I included the class

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried this before but sadly didn't work, it says that 'self' is not defind.

Comment: @mmm Because the methods need to have a `self` first parameter. You'll want to look into how to write classes and methods for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the methods as static class methods. Here are two ways to fix your code:

1. using `@staticmethod`. Less preferred method, uses class methods (not object-oriented):

```py
class test_cpu:
    @staticmethod  # changed
    def f(x):
        while True:
            x * x

    @staticmethod  # changed
    def load(cores):
        print("utilizing %d cores" % (cores / 2))
        pool = Pool(10)
        pool.map(test_cpu.f, range(6))  # changed
```

2. adding `self` and creating a `test_cpu` instance:

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool


class test_cpu:
    def f(self, x):  # changed
        while True:
            x * x

    def load(self, cores):  # changed
        print("utilizing %d cores" % (cores / 2))
        pool = Pool(10)
        pool.map(self.f, range(6))  # changed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("There are %d CPUs in your PC" % multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    cores_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    input_user = input("What do you want to tes? type CPU, Memory or Both: ")
    input_user.lower()
    test_cpu_instance = test_cpu()  # changed
    if input_user == "cpu":
        test_cpu_instance.load(cores_count)  # changed
```